# How to strip parts of the given url using preg_replace (php)

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I need to get

`dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek.jpg`

from

`http://dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek-300x199.jpg?w=360`

Please help how to get this by using preg_replace ?

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, you don't need a regular expression, you can just [parse the url](http://php.net/parse_url)

```
$url = 'http://dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek-300x199.jpg?w=360';
$parts = parse_url($url);
echo $parts['host'] . $parts['path'];
```

Missed that you want to strip the size ...

```
$data = preg_replace('/(-\d+x\d+)\.jpg/', '.jpg', $data);
```

Comment: +1, anyways you will most likely have to filter the 300x199 out afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_replace` with an array:

```
$url = "http://dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek-300x199.jpg?w=360";

$replace = array(
           '~http://~',           // http part
           '~-\d+x\d+(?=\.jpg)~', // size before .jpg
           '~\?\S*$~');           // query

$url = preg_replace($replace, "", $url);
```

[test @ eval.in](https://eval.in/183969)

```
dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need preg_replace for it

```
<?php
$url = 'http://dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek-300x199.jpg?w=360';
$start = strpos($url, '//');
echo substr($url,$start+2,strpos($url, '?'));//dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek-300x199.jpg?w=360


echo substr($url,0,strpos($url, '?'));//http://dev.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sheep-shrek-300x199.jpg
?>
```

Comment: Wrong answer, this will not give him the result he wants - read the question clearly.

Comment: @Xatenev practically he will be needing image url without params Please think practically before downvote and if you have this much time so please answer question rather than talking unpractically

Comment: ?? Its totally good that you parsed the params out. But aswell he wanted to delete "http://" and "-300x199" from his URL. This is just the half answer. -> Why am I not answering the question? Because @Darhazer already posted a very good answer on this issue.

Comment: @Xatenev i have given both option and the another one also which is unpractical but important to you ha ha:)